# Base of system of vectors in the vector space $\mathbb{k}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and consider vector space $\mathbb{k}^n$ over $\mathbb{k}$.

Prove that any  collection $X$ of vectors in $\mathbb{k}^n$ which contains at least one nonzero vector has a linearly independent subcollection $X'$ such that $\langle X\rangle =\langle X'\rangle $. Any such subcollection $X'$ is called *a base* for the given collection $X$.

**My approach:** Since $X$ has a vector $v\neq 0$. Then easy to see that $\langle v\rangle \subseteq\langle X\rangle$.

If $\langle v\rangle =\langle X\rangle$ then we are done since $v$ is linearly independent because $v\neq 0$.

Suppose that $\langle v\rangle \subsetneq\langle X\rangle$ then one can take the vector $v_1\in \langle X\rangle$ such that $v_1\notin \langle v\rangle$. Then easy to see that $\{v,v_1\}$ is linearly independent and $\langle v,v_1\rangle \subseteq\langle X\rangle$.

I was thinking that I solved the problem but the vector $v_1$ is in linear span of $X$ but we need the vector from $X$. I have spent some time trying to overcome this obstacle but failed.

Would be very thankful if someone can show how to solve it correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle=\langle S\rangle$, therefore $\langle v\rangle\subsetneq\langle X\rangle$ implies $X\nsubseteq \langle v\rangle$ and, more generally, $\langle S\rangle\subsetneq \langle X\rangle$ implies $X\nsubseteq \langle S\rangle$. Therefore $v_1$ may be chosen to be in $X$.

Comment: But what is $\langle \langle S \rangle \rangle$? Can you show why it is equal linear span of $S$?

Comment: @ZFR It's $\langle\bullet\rangle$ of $\langle S\rangle$.

Comment: It is a really nice trick! I suppose that i would not be able to come up with this on my own. Maybe this is a frequent teick in linear algebra however i began to study this subject deeply just one week ago :)

Comment: @ZFR You should be conscious, however, that the detail you have been focusing on does not tackle in the slightest the fact that this procedure should eventually produce a generating set.

Comment: I fuess this process will produce generating set because every time we get linearly independent collection and this process will terminate after a finite number of steps since we are in the space $k^n$.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't answer to my last question

Comment: Specifically, what's your question?

Comment: You said that the detail which i am focusing does not solve the problem, right?

Comment: @ZFR Per se it doesn't prove that the process of adding a new vector needs to terminate eventually. You said you guessed that the process should terminate in a finite number of steps, and I took your word for it.